# How Create NSMenuItem with Collapsed Arrow?

Tags: swift

How code in Swift this collapsed/uncollapsed menuBarItem that exists in Wifi menu?

collapsedMode:
[image]

uncollapsedMode:
[image]

Comment: It is a menu item like any other